# Vue: CSS does not apply to D3's svg when using scoped

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, d3.js, svg

So this is the code for my component:

```html
<template>
  <div id="something" class="card">
  </div>
</template>
```

```
const height = 200;
const width = 200;

let graph = d3
  .select('#something')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart-container')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width);
```

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.chart-container {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
</style>
```

The svg does have the class `.chart-container` applied to, but there is no style applied to

[image: The image of the inspection tool]

However, when I remove `scoped` from `<style lang="scss">`, it works.

[image: The image of the inspection tool when the code working as intended]

Why does it behave that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked really less on `svg` styling , but I know that you can't change a style of appended elements directly. You need  Deep Selectors to apply to that

Here is the link - https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles

Have a look to this sandbox I have created which shows what happened

Just look on the `components/helloWorld.vue`

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-qd1d4?fontsize=14